# Как передать значение из input в яндекс карту? И чтобы сразу шел поиск по карте в поле input?

Tags: яндекс-карты, search

Вот часть кода:

```
function onZonesLoad(json) {
        // Добавляем зоны на карту.
        var deliveryZones = ymaps.geoQuery(json).addToMap(map);
        // Задаём цвет и контент балунов полигонов.
        deliveryZones.each(function (obj) {
            obj.options.set({
                fillColor: obj.properties.get('fill'),
                fillOpacity: obj.properties.get('fill-opacity'),
                strokeColor: obj.properties.get('stroke'),
                strokeWidth: obj.properties.get('stroke-width'),
                strokeOpacity: obj.properties.get('stroke-opacity')
            }); searchControl.events.add('load', function(){
            let geoObjectsArray = searchControl.getResultsArray();
            if (geoObjectsArray.length === 1){
                highlightResult(searchControl.getResultsArray()[0]);
            } else {
                $(document).on('click', '.result_item', function(){
                    let result = $(this).attr('data-count');
                    highlightResult(searchControl.getResultsArray()[result]);
                    searchControl.showResult(result);
                    $('#select_result').slideUp();
                });
            }
        });
            obj.properties.set({
                balloonContent: obj.properties.get('description'),
                hintContent: obj.properties.get('description')
            });
        });

        // Проверим попадание результата поиска в одну из зон доставки.
        searchControl.events.add('resultshow', function (e) {
            highlightResult(searchControl.getResultsArray()[e.get('index')]);
        });

        // Проверим попадание метки геолокации в одну из зон доставки.
        map.controls.get('geolocationControl').events.add('locationchange', function (e) {
            highlightResult(e.get('geoObjects').get(0));
        });

        // При перемещении метки сбрасываем подпись, содержимое балуна и перекрашиваем метку.
        deliveryPoint.events.add('dragstart', function () {
            deliveryPoint.properties.set({iconCaption: '', balloonContent: ''});
            deliveryPoint.options.set('iconColor', 'black');
        });

        // По окончании перемещения метки вызываем функцию выделения зоны доставки.
        deliveryPoint.events.add('dragend', function () {
            highlightResult(deliveryPoint);
        });

        function highlightResult(obj) {
            // Сохраняем координаты переданного объекта.
            var coords = obj.geometry.getCoordinates(),
            // Находим полигон, в который входят переданные координаты.
                polygon = deliveryZones.searchContaining(coords).get(0);
```